# Left-flushing and aligning equations without having some parts align center

Tags: align

This is my attempt:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{align*}
\text{a)}\quad abc &= 1, & x &= 2\\
\text{b)}\quad zw &= 3,  & q &= 3 
\end{align*}
```

which results in this:

[image: 1]

But what I want is this:

[image: 2]

I also tried using `flalign*`, but I couldn't figure out the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alignat` adds no extra space

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  \text{a)}&&\quad abc &= 1,\quad & x &= 2\\
\text{b)}&&\quad zw &= 3,\quad  & q &= 3 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```